# export input query from one GET request and use them on separate requests

Tags: javascript, rest, http, get, module-export

I am trying to use the input of the user on my `RESTful API` in the query for one `GET` request and use that data to randomize a number and use that info for the rest of the application. any guidance about best solution to store the values and use them on different blocks throughout the application is appreciated.
Part of the code sample is as below:

```
    app.get("/start", (req, res) => {
        const numberOfFigures = req.query.figures;
        const randomBaseNumber = Math.random();
        const theNumber = (randomBaseNumber * 10 ** numberOfFigures).toFixed(0);
        res.send(`guess the ${numberOfFigures} digit number!`);

    app.get("/guess", (req, res) => {
        let guessedNumber = req.query.guess;
        if (guessedNumber !== theNumber) {
            console.log("Wrong! Guess again");
        }
```

I am trying to use for instance theNumber value from /Start request in the /guess request!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep `theNumber` variable outside of the scope of both callbacks e.g.

```
    let theNumber = 0
    app.get("/start", (req, res) => {
        const numberOfFigures = req.query.figures;
        const randomBaseNumber = Math.random();
        theNumber = (randomBaseNumber * 10 ** numberOfFigures).toFixed(0);
        res.send(`guess the ${numberOfFigures} digit number!`);

    app.get("/guess", (req, res) => {
        let guessedNumber = req.query.guess;
        if (guessedNumber !== theNumber) {
            console.log("Wrong! Guess again");
        }
```

I would also use POST for the `/guess` endpoint

Comment: but the global value will remain zero as  let theNumber = 0 and will not update for the next endpoint! right?

Comment: `theNumber = (randomBaseNumber * 10 ** numberOfFigures).toFixed(0)` will update the value

Comment: yes it will but within the scope right? I am using this notion but for the next scope or endpoint theNumber will reset to original global value not the updated one!

Comment: you might need to declare it as `this.theNumber` and address it as such

Answer (score 0):

The following 3 ways of storing data come to mind:

1. Declare **theNumber** as a global variable.
2. Store the variable in a json and import it when needed (eg: fs module).
3. Store it in a database (eg: MongoDB).

Method 1 is the easiest way. The variable will be accessible from all the routes, and it will be erased if your app restarts.

```
let theNumber = 0;
...
app.get("/start", (req, res) => {
    theNumber = ...
    ...
```

Methods 2 and 3 will make the variable, once created, persist even if the app restarts. However, for this simple use case, I'd say they're overkill.

Comment: yeah the global variable will turn into original value and since it is a random number I have to store or export and import it for the next endpoint right? otherwise it wont work I believe. On the other hand I tried different exporting module technique which yet were fruitless. I need to export the start query as the base of the calculations. the rest is ok. How can I get a query value on an endpoint and store it as a JSON and import it for the next endpoint? this is the main struggle for me

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the "fs" module in node.js, particularly the writeFile method. It's a good starting point if you want to store variables in a json. Just create a variables.json file (name it whatever you want), write theNumber value to the json after creation, require the json file wherever you need to use theNumber value (something like: const jsonValues = require('path_to_variables.json'); ), and access it as the json property (let theNumber = jsonValues.theNumber;).

Comment: I did that for all the variables. the only one I can not figure it out yet is const numberOfFigures = req.query.figures; I can not figure out how to export it and import it to another JSON so it will be reserved const.

Comment: It should work the same for all variables, unless the issue is somewhere else. Did you print req.query.figures? Is it undefined? Are you sending the value in the query properly? (Like so: /start?figures=3). Does it work for req.query.guess? Asking these questions might help you get to the solution.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to reassign actually. and my arguments were the same as my parameters. That was the reason I was confused. It worked. Thanks